# iOS Swift: Crash on deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, icloud, cloudkit

I'm getting a crash when I remove a row from a tableView. Not sure what's going on. Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let items = days[indexPath.row]
        self.removeItems(items, indexPath: indexPath)
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return days.count
}
```

removeItems

```
func removeItems(items: [CKRecord], indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    for item in items {
        db.deleteRecordWithID(item.recordID) { (record, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                if let index = find(exercises, item) {
                    exercises.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    days.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: can you show numberOfRowsInSection & numberOfSections method?

Comment: There is only one section. Just added the number of rows method.

Comment: replace deleteRowsAtIndexPaths with reloadData. and log days.count. look what happen.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't remove the row with animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before removing cells (or adding) you need to call `beginUpdates()` on the involved tableView. Then remove, or add cells. When finished, call `endUpdates()`.
Once you call `endUpdates()`. Remember that once you call `endUpdates()` your tableView model must be consistent with the number of sections and rows you removed or added.
Begin and End updates allows the ui to present a coherent unique animation for all the cell changes.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```